# https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm using Python and the docx lib.
I need help with printing out the contents of a docx file which include paragraphs and table in the same order the document has them.
I'm using the docx library but I've only figure out how to print all the paragraphs first followed by all the tables. However in my document I have paragraphs and tables interleaved and I want to preserve the order.

Comment: Saw your tittle. Added relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not implemented yet (and doesn't exist at all in the MS API), but there's a workaround you can use here:

https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40#issuecomment-60337012

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I'm new to python and I'm having trouble making your code snippet work.  The import statements didn't work as is for the latest docx with python 2.7.6.  Also, I'm ramping up on how to use the yield command. Would you happen to have a simple but complete example that reads in a docx and prints out the paragraphs and tables in text?  This would be a huge help.

Comment: You're right, some of the imports needed to change locations due to refactoring in a recent release. I've updated the example at that link to reflect those.